# Google crome not install

Tags: google-chrome

When i install google crome I am getting this error. Help me

I have run this command in tem directory

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

after that i run this command

```
sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome*.deb
```

I am getting this error

```
jaskaran@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome*.debdpkg: error processing ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Please check it

Answer (score 2):

You're running a 32-bit system, so you need to install the 32-bit package version, not the 64-bit one.

Do the following in the terminal:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Comment: Warning: in March 2016 Google ended the support of 32-bit Chrome version for Linux. These commands won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `amd64` with `i386` in the link. You are using a 32-bit installation of Ubuntu, and that link is for the 64-bit version of Chrome.